# Hash set function for hashing

Tags: c++, hash, set

I am trying to implement a hash set but I have some trouble for the hash function. I want to add in the set, persons that have name and phone number:

```
class Person{
    string name;
    long long int phoneNumber;
}
```

And my indexes in the set are calculated by summing the digits of the phoneNumber. The problem is that I dont want my functions to be something like this:

```
int add(long long int nr, Element e) - the function that adds an Element to the set
{
     int hashCode = hash(nr);;
     ...
}
```

where the `long long int nr` should be the phoneNumber and `Element e` should be the Person. I mean, it's pretty stupid. If I already have the person as parameter, why have it's phoneNumber too? As you can see I am using templates, and my teacher advised me to do a virtual class for the hashFunction to force it to be the respective type(something like the HashSet in Java). The thing is I have NO IDEA how to do that. Do you have any ideas that could help me?

Comment: A phone number isn't an integer, it's a string of digits.

Comment: @sftrabbit Whatever! That's not the point.

Comment: It's a bit strange to use a telephone number as an index. A phone number does not normally identify a person. It is possible to write a telephone number multiple ways, so the telephone number needs to be *canonicalized* before it can be used as an index. Finally, if you want to have a lookup based on a telephone number, you are better off using a (hash) **map** instead of a **set**.

Answer (score 0):

If you do :

```
 int add(Person p, Element e)
```

You will restrict you hastset class to be completely dependent on `Person` class. Taking integer or string value into the hash method is more plausible in this way. You can determine the parameter to hash outside the hash method and give it as an input.

Moreover, when you add another member to Person class like age and use in in the hashing, you will also need to modify the hash method to use this particular member.

Comment: @faith_k  I want to do `void add(Person* p)` and the add function know how to caculate the index: int hash = int hashCode(p->phoneNumber)

Comment: @MonsterMonster I don't understand, what is keeping you from doing just that?